# how to check if image exists on server or not using smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

i want to do something like this

```
{if image_exists}

<img src='{$path}{$imagename}'>

{else}

<img src='{$path}default.jpg'>

{/if}
```

how do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than having Smarty doing the logic, I'd say it's better to have the actual PHP doing it instead.

In PHP you can do something like:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
    $path = $filename;
} 
else 
{
    $path = 'default.jpg';
}
```

Then in the template you won't need any `if` statement. Simply use the `img` tag as you would normally.

```
<img src="{$path}" />
```

If you really want to do the check in the template file, just use the PHP function normally with Smarty's `if` statement.

```
{if file_exists($path . $imagename)}

<img src='{$path}{$imagename}'>

{else}

<img src='{$path}default.jpg'>

{/if}
```

Comment: but i am using smartyloop in tpl file , that's why i need smarty to check

Comment: Well you can simply have the loop in PHP and do the check too, can't you? Also if you really want to have the check in the template file, you can just do the same thing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It works fine on my machine. I've just tested it. Which Smarty version are you using? Also, are you using some sort of framework?

Answer (score 3):

Smarty file_exists function accepts only the absolute path.

so u can do like below:

```
{assign var="specialmsg" value="/var/www/html/public/uploads/{$logo}"}
{if file_exists({$specialmsg})}
\\SOME CODE HERE
{else}
\\ELSE CODE HERE
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{if $(image variable whatever u used) ne ""}{$pathtoimagedirectory}/{$imagename}{else}{$path to default image}/{$defaultimagename}{/if}
```